# CSS animation-direction: alternate not working

Tags: css, css-animations

Can anybody tell why CSS animation direction property is not working?

Animation is working properly but alternate property is not working...

```css
.w3-animate-top{
  border : 6px solid red;
  animation-duration : 10s;
  margin-top : 300px;
}

.main{
    height : 100px;
    border : 6px solid white;
    text-align : center;
    background-color : yellow;
    animation-name : example;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  to {
    background-color: white;}
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>
  
  <div class = 'main'>
    My Animation
    <p>hello rishi this is rajan</p>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define **animation-iteration-count** property with value like `number|infinite|initial|inherit`
**Example:** `animation-iteration-count: infinite;`

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-iteration-count.asp

```css
.w3-animate-top{
  border : 6px solid red;
  animation-duration : 10s;
  margin-top : 300px;
}

.main{
    height : 100px;
    border : 6px solid white;
    text-align : center;
    background-color : yellow;
    animation-name : example;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  to {
    background-color: white;}
  }
}
```

```html
<div class = 'main'>
    My Animation
    <p>Hello Rishi, This is Raeesh</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign at least 2 interations for this animation to make it finish the alternate animation:

```
animation-iteration-count: 2;
```

See [`animation-iteration-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count)

As an addition, you can assign [`animation-fill-mode: both;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) to make the element stay at both states before and after the animation.

```css
.w3-animate-top{
  border : 6px solid red;
  animation-duration : 10s;
  margin-top : 300px;
}

.main{
    height : 100px;
    border : 6px solid white;
    text-align : center;
    background-color : yellow;
    animation-name : example;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-iteration-count: 2;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  to {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class = 'main'>
  My Animation
  <p>hello rishi this is rajan</p>
</div>
```

Or you can make it loop forever by assigning

```
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```